# Float random with value from "1.3000 to 1.4000" is possible?

Tags: android, floating-point

Its possible to make float random from range 1.3000 to 1.4000? That give me numbers like 13405, 13855 etc.
I know double is more flexible with range floating point, but i cant use it.

So i create something like:

```
  float highmax = 0.6500f;
        float highlow = 0.7000f;
        float generatedFloatHigh = highmax + new Random().nextFloat() * (highlow - highmax);
```

But this not work what i want.

Any suggestion? Or maybe i should look for other libraly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to get a random number(for example x) between 0 and 1000, then you can get a number from range 1.3000 to 1.4000 like this :

```
int x = new Random(1000).nextInt();
float result = 1.3000f + x*0.0001f;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Random generator = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
int n = generator.nextInt(1000);
float generatedFloatHigh = 1.3000 + n/1000;
```